# Build hierarchical list from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of categories that looks something like

```
array(
  array(
    'id' => '1',
    'path' => '1',
    'children_count' => '16',
    'name' => 'A'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '3',
    'path' => '1/2/3',
    'children_count' => '0',
    'name' => 'C'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '2',
    'path' => '1/2',
    'children_count' => '9',
    'name' => 'B'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '4',
    'path' => '1/2/4',
    'children_count' => '0',
    'name' => 'D'
  )
)
```

What I'm trying to build is a hierarchal array (the `path` key shows the relation based on `id`), so the output is in the correct order (root parent first, then children, then more children) and indent the `name` based on how far down in the child is.  The end result should look something like:

```
A
-B
--C
--D
```

Here's what I have so far, but it's obviously not working

```
$categoryTree = array();

foreach ($categories as $category) {

    $categoryTree[(string)$category['path']] = str_repeat("-", substr_count($category['path'], "/")) . $category['name'];
}

ksort($categoryTree);

var_export($categoryTree);
```

Which comes out to:

```
array (
  '1/2' => '-B',
  '1/2/3' => '--C',
  '1/2/4' => '--D',
  1 => 'A'
)
```

How can I get these in the correct order? (and if siblings could be ordered by `id` that would be dandy too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on One Trick Pony's answer, but correctly handles IDs with more than one digit.

```
foreach ($categories as $category)
  $output[$category['path']] =
    str_repeat('-', substr_count($category['path'], '/')) . $category['name'];

$paths = array_keys($output);
natsort($paths);

foreach ($paths as $path) {
  echo $output[$path], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of slashes to generate the value prefixes, then sort by path (key) ?

```
foreach ($categories as $category)
  $output[$category['path']] =
    str_repeat('-', substr_count($category['path'], '/')) . $category['name'];

ksort($output, SORT_STRING);
```

Comment: Will this group items in the same part of the hierarchy together? E.g. if you have 1/2, 1/5, 1/2/3, 1/2/4, 1/5/6, 1/5/7.

Comment: Yes, isn't that the intended output? (1/2, 1/2/3, 1/2/4, 1/5...)